# Changing View Sizes when Scrolled

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view with a couple of views in it. I want the views to be displayed such that the size of the view in the middle of the scrollview is the largest and the size of the other views keep decreasing from the middle to the ends. Also, when the view is scrolled, the views should be resized to follow this behavior. How do I start about with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try having your view controller adapt the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol and then use the **scrollViewDidScrollFunction**.

Inside the function you can check the content offset of your scrollview and resize your images accordingly. Something like:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset; 

    // In here goes your resizing code
}
```

Cheers